# How to add the Google Analytics tag to website developed with Streamlit?

Tags: python, html, google-analytics, fastapi, streamlit

I would like to track in Google Analytics a UI I built with Streamlit.
According to Google Analytics, the following needs to be added into the <head> section of the HTML.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-**********"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-**********');
</script>
```

As I do not have any html file in my code architecture, I included the following Streamlit line in my main .py file:

```
google_analytics_js = '[previous_html_code]'
st.components.v1.html(google_analytics_js)
```

The website is unfortunately not tracked. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [How to add Google Analytics or JS code in a Streamlit app?](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-add-google-analytics-or-js-code-in-a-streamlit-app/1610/27)

Comment: Thanks. I saw that yes, but no discussed solution in that page worked in my case

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the component HTML will be added to an iframe, you need to allow its script to access the parent:

```
<script crossorigin='anonymous'>
add script
</script>
```

In addition to that, whenever the script accesses `window` or `document`, you should use `parent.window` and `parent.document`.